# spindump for Windows Kernel Debugging Devstudio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, kernel, windbg

So, when running into a deadlock, mutex, lock reversal etc etc, on OSX the `spindump` tool is quite useful. It just dumps *all* the thread stacks on the system (userland and kernel) and it is fairly visible as to what threads are blocked.

Now using Devstudio to do Kernel Debugging on 2nd VM, I encounter a deadlock. I see I can use "!process 0 0" to dump all processes. And I believe I can switch to a process, and dump threads (?), then pick a thread with "!thread " and "k" to see the stack. But there are literally thousands of threads, surely there is a way to dump them all without manually doing it?

"!process 0 7" runs for about 40mins, and set none of the stacks has my functions in them.

spindump output looks like

  `Thread 0x8ab              1000 samples (1-1000)     priority 81 (base 81)
 *1000  call_continuation + 23 (kernel.development + 1927415) 
   *1000  arc_reclaim_thread + 2391 (arc.c:5095,11 in zfs + 131367)
     *1000  cv_timedwait_hires + 206 (spl-condvar.c:172,14 in spl + 8125) 
       *1000  msleep + 98 (kernel.development + 7434066) 
         *1000  _sleep + 219 (kernel.development + 7432603) 
           *1000  lck_mtx_sleep_deadline + 147 (kernel.development + 2362339) 
             *1000  thread_block_reason + 286 (kernel.development + 2407438)`

So nothing magical there, just that it iterates through all threads.

Comment: "!process 0 0" and find System process address, then "!process 0xdeadbeef 7" seems to at least lists threads in kernel with my functions in the stacks. Takes nearly 12 mins on my VM though.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? To me it seems you know that there's a deadlock, but you don't know whether it's in the kernel or in user mode and you don't know which application is affected. It seems to me like you want a general purpose solve-it-all deadlock tool. What would you do if you find that Microsoft Office is in a deadlock with Adobe Reader? What's the next step then?

Comment: I know there is a deadlock, since threads waiting for a new vnode wait forever, so I need to see the stacks to know who holds that mutex so I can work out why it is not returning. Yes, most of those stacks are in kernel, but some can be userland (the cmdline tools that call into the kernel). And yeah, spinlock is pretty close to a universal deadlock tool, but in my case, I am working on a filesystem driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use !stacks with 0,1,2

quoted from the windbg chm file

```
The !stacks extension gives a brief summary of the state of every thread. You   
can use this extension instead of the !process extension to get a quick overview    
of the system, especially when debugging multithread issues such as resource    
conflicts or deadlocks.

The !findstack user-mode extension also displays information about particular stacks.

Here is an example of the simplest !stacks display:

kd> !stacks 0
Proc.Thread  .Thread  ThreadState  Blocker
                                     [System]
   4.000050  827eea10  Blocked    +0xfe0343a5

                                     [smss.exe]

                                     [csrss.exe]
  b0.0000a8  82723b70  Blocked    ntoskrnl!_KiSystemService+0xc4
  b0.0000c8  82719620  Blocked    ntoskrnl!_KiSystemService+0xc4
  b0.0000d0  827d5d50  Blocked    ntoskrnl!_KiSystemService+0xc4
.....
```

edit

!stacks is a time consuming operation 
the speed is relative to the transport being used
vm to vm has its own overhead 
on a physical connection to a physical machine with net debugging or a 
1394 on a pre win 10 is quiet faster than com port or pipe with 115200 baudrate

i am not sure what your vm is but if you are on vbox then you can try vmkd

any way to answer your comment

you can run this to log and grep the output

**.logopen z:\foo.txt ; !stacks 0; .logclose**

that will open a log file in your desired path and redirect all the output to the log file and close the log file once the command completes

also keep in mind !stacks accepts a wildcard filter string so that only stacks with a symbols that you know can be filtered

like

```
kd> .logopen c:\stacks.txt ; !stacks 0  Etw; .logclose
Opened log file 'c:\stacks.txt'

Proc.Thread  .Thread  Ticks   ThreadState Blocker

Max cache size is       : 1048576 bytes (0x400 KB) 
Total memory in cache   : 0 bytes (0 KB) 
Number of regions cached: 0
0 full reads broken into 0 partial reads
    counts: 0 cached/0 uncached, 0.00% cached
    bytes : 0 cached/0 uncached, 0.00% cached
** Prototype PTEs are implicitly decoded
                            [82965600 Idle]
                            [840dcc40 System]
   4.000078  8410ed48 0000081 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000080  8410e4d8 0000081 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000084  84142020 0000081 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000088  84142d48 0000081 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000090  8416c630 000001d Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000094  8496ea88 0000bf3 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.0000a0  84079a88 000004a Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000194  85144d48 000445c Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000308  851b9d48 0004035 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.00032c  851d3d48 0002d48 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.00034c  852e8d48 0003e4a Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000350  84973d48 0003df4 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000354  84f0dd48 0003de4 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0
   4.000444  854c7970 0002158 Blocked    nt!EtwpLogger+0xd0

                            [84f0b930 smss.exe]

                            [8409eb38 csrss.exe]

                            [84f34d40 wininit.exe]

                            [84f4d030 csrss.exe]

                            [850f8d40 winlogon.exe]

                            [8515bb38 services.exe]

                            [85161d40 lsass.exe]

                            [85163d40 lsm.exe]
```

Comment: Ah thank you. Weird how I did not find anyone mentioning !stacks, nor the docs, with all the surfing I did. Guess that just means I'm poor at googling. :)  Next up is getting that output to a txt file so I can grep it or something, since the Search feature in "intermediate window" is the worst thing ever :)

Comment: Although, even just "!stacks 0" takes 12mins to dump with my small VM. Is this how you pro windows devs work, just a whole heap of patience? (Two VMs, using TCP over localhost debugging).

Comment: .logopen z:\foo.bar;!stacks 0; .logclose

Comment: Ohh the searchstring is definitely useful. Thanks!

Comment: Once I had my stack list, it was quick to find. Porting mistake with atomics, c11 ones take ptrs, but win32 does not. This was very informative, thanks everyone.